# PyQt5: Qt .qrc resource files and video files

Tags: qt, video, pyqt5

I'm coding a Windows desktop app which uses video files (audio / visual) and I would like to know which format (avi, mp4, etc) is best for using in a resource file (.qrc) and then to be converted for use by PyQt5.

I have checked for an answer to this but there is very little documentation which leads me to think that there is a possibility that I'm asking a question which has no positive outcome.

Apologies to admins if this looks like I'm asking for an opinion but I do believe there is an answer aside from having a folder containing the videos.

Comment: You are asking for opinions unless you can provide a way to quantify what "best" means. A resource file is simply a form of archive with optional compression (like `tar`+`gzip`). I assume you must know that most common audio/video formats are *already* compressed - so putting them in a resource file is not going to make them any smaller.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm asking from the point of view of adding to a resource file with the intention of then packing it all into an executable file so that the a/v content can only be accessed via the app. What I mean by best is: easiest to convert to a python/pyqt5 resource file without any degradation - as there is no documentation about this it would be good to know whether I should use AVI or MP4. I am thinking that AVI (don't know which audio codec though) would be the better option.

Comment: I thought I already explained that. It makes no difference whatsoever. It's just an archive format. Like all such formats (`tar`, `zip`, etc), it stores files as a stream of bytes. Compression is optional. Multimedia formats like MP3/AVI are *already* heavily degraded by the lossy compression algorithms they use, so it seems pointless to worry about that anyway.

Comment: @ekhumoro You have answered my question fully. Apologies for my lack of understanding, the information you have provided is of great use